# How can I use `git diff --color-words` outside a Git repository?

Tags: git, colors, diff, word-diff

How can I get output like in  `git diff --color-words`, but outside Git?

Closest thing is `wdiff  -t`, but it underlines/inverts things instead of using green/red colours and does not allow specifying my whitespace regex.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

```
git diff --color-words --no-index old.txt new.txt
```

Comment: From the manpage: "If exactly two paths are given and at least one points outside the current repository, git diff will compare the two files / directories. This behavior can be forced by --no-index." (A lot of times you don't even need `--no-index`.)

Comment: At least in my git 1.9.3, the order should be `git diff --no-index --color-words`

Comment: In my git v1.9.3 order of `--no-index` and `--color-words` does not matter... (Actually I can't find a case now where it fails without `--no-index` at all).

Comment: Works great. Maybe we can add an alias `alias diff="git diff --no-index"`?

Answer (score 8):

According to a comment from Jefromi you can just use

```
git diff --color-words file1 file2
```

outside of git repositories too.

Comment: git diff didn't work on two arbit files as mentioned above. (git version 1.7.4).
Although,`git diff --color-words --no-index <file1> <file2>` works, correct approach would be to use wdiff, which is intended for that purpose (http://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/)

Comment: @Manu No, `git diff` is intended for this purpose.  `wdiff` is just a hack.  Read your link sometime.

Comment: `git diff` is excellent, but the `wdiff` page noted above does not say that it's a hack.  wdiff "is quite mature" according to its own documentation linked from that page: https://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/manual/wdiff.html

Answer (score 3):

**Git version 1.9.1:**

`git diff --word-diff=color fileA fileB`

Answer (score 2):

If I'm inside a git repository (git v2.3.3) :

- `git diff --color-words` doesn't work (no output)
- `git diff --no-index` doesn't accept `--color-words` nor `--color` arguments

Using wdiff is possible, configured to use colors, rather than underlined :

```
wdiff -n \
  -w $'\033[30;31m' -x $'\033[0m' \
  -y $'\033[30;32m' -z $'\033[0m' \
  … | less -R
```

Source : https://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/manual/html_node/wdiff-Examples.html (modified to use foreground colors rather than background colors)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why `git --no-index --color-words` fails? I used it (with earlier Git versions although).

Answer (score 1):

you can say `git diff --color=always --color-words`, which will give you the color escape codes in the output. you are going to have some shell to interpret the color codes though …

Comment: The question was about using it outside Git repository. Also it misses some things when `--color-words=always` instead of just `--color-words`.

Comment: @vi: sorry, you only said »outside git«, it did not mention a repository anywhere. i thought it was about having the color in other applications beside git (when e.g. piped) – which is also »outside git«, in the sense of »not inside the default git toolchain/tool collection«