# How to compare two files not in repo using git

Tags: git, compare, diff

I'd like to compare two css files which are not in any git repository. Is there such a functionality in git?

Comment: What if I wanted to use, say, the `--patience` flag?  Do you know a **diff(1)** that can do that?

Comment: You should accept Kyle Burton's answer.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855767/can-i-use-git-diff-on-untracked-files?rq=1

Answer (score 297, accepted):

`git`'s diff is more functional than the standard unix `diff`.  I often want to do this and since this question ranks highly on google, I want this answer to show up.

This question: [How to use `git diff --color-words` outside a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637311/how-to-use-git-diff-color-words-outside-a-git-repository)

Shows how to use git to diff files where at least one of them is not in the repository by using `--no-index`:

```
git diff --no-index file1.txt file2.txt
```

It doesn't matter which one is tracked by git and which is not - one or both can be untracked, eg:

```
$ date > x
$ sleep 2
$ date > y
$ git diff --color-words --no-index x y
diff --git a/x b/y
index 6b10c7c..70f036c 100644
--- a/x
+++ a/y
@@ -1 + 1 @@
Wed Jun 10 10:57:45|10:57:47 EDT 2013
```

The color can't be shown here so I separated the changes with a pipe in the example.

Comment: If you wanted this behavior default, you could add an alias to your `.bashrc` file (or whatever you use): `alias diff="git diff --no-index"`

Comment: FYI: On Git for Windows there was a [bug (#2123)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2123) that "--no-index" was not respected. This was fixed in Git for Windows v2.21.0 (February 26th 2019).

Comment: What does row "index 6b10c7c..70f036c 100644" mean? I am comparing 2 binaries, they differ, but that is the only row with difference...

Comment: hi @LukasSalich it looks like that line format might be documented by git (eg: https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-format) git's diff doesn't attempt to diff binaries afaik, so I'm guessing that line means they differ, the two SHAs where a change was identified and then the permissions of the file.

Comment: Note that you don't have to specify `--no-index` if you're doing this outside of any Git repository.

Comment: I use git diff on 2 files (in my working directory) where they are both version-controlled. So theoretically, i can exclude --no-index.  But strange, output is empty.   Once i put --no-index, it shows diff output.

Answer (score 6):

`diff -u`

will give similar unified context output to git's diff.

Comment: It does not do nice coloring or use a pager, however.

Comment: It does not allow a nice word diff, either (`git diff --word-diff`).

Answer (score 2):

Just use the diff command:

```
diff file1.ext file2.ext
```

Comment: Hmkay, I tried this but in my opinion, the output was just nonsense... Maybe I was wrong...

Comment: you can run some GUI tool that will provide better view, like gvimdiff, kompare or similar