# Using jq or alternative command line tools to compare JSON files

Tags: json, diff, jq

Are there any command line utilities that can be used to find if two JSON files are identical with invariance to within-dictionary-key and within-list-element ordering?

Could this be done with [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) or some other equivalent tool?

### Examples:

These two JSON files are identical

`A`:

```
{
  "People": ["John", "Bryan"],
  "City": "Boston",
  "State": "MA"
}
```

`B`:

```
{
  "People": ["Bryan", "John"],
  "State": "MA",
  "City": "Boston"
}
```

but these two JSON files are different:

`A`:

```
{
  "People": ["John", "Bryan", "Carla"],
  "City": "Boston",
  "State": "MA"
}
```

`C`:

```
{
  "People": ["Bryan", "John"],
  "State": "MA",
  "City": "Boston"
}
```

That would be:

```
$ some_diff_command A.json B.json

$ some_diff_command A.json C.json
The files are not structurally identical
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Since jq's comparison already compares objects without taking into account key ordering, all that's left is to sort all lists inside the object before comparing them. Assuming your two files are named `a.json` and `b.json`, on the latest jq nightly:

```
jq --argfile a a.json --argfile b b.json -n '($a | (.. | arrays) |= sort) as $a | ($b | (.. | arrays) |= sort) as $b | $a == $b'
```

This program should return "true" or "false" depending on whether or not the objects are equal using the definition of equality you ask for.

EDIT: The `(.. | arrays) |= sort` construct doesn't actually work as expected on some edge cases. [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/893) explains why and provides some alternatives, such as:

```
def post_recurse(f): def r: (f | select(. != null) | r), .; r; def post_recurse: post_recurse(.[]?); (post_recurse | arrays) |= sort
```

Applied to the jq invocation above:

```
jq --argfile a a.json --argfile b b.json -n 'def post_recurse(f): def r: (f | select(. != null) | r), .; r; def post_recurse: post_recurse(.[]?); ($a | (post_recurse | arrays) |= sort) as $a | ($b | (post_recurse | arrays) |= sort) as $b | $a == $b'
```

Comment: I've been trying to change `--argfile a a.json` for `--arg a $a` (being $a a json string), with no luck. any idea how to approach strings, not files?

Comment: @SimonErnestoCardenasZarate if you are still having this problem, you may be wanting the `--argjson` argument instead

Answer (score 259):

If your shell supports process substitution (Bash-style follows, see [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution)):

```
diff <(jq --sort-keys . A.json) <(jq --sort-keys . B.json)
```

Objects key order will be ignored, but array order will still matter. It is possible to work-around that, if desired, by sorting array values in some other way, or making them set-like (e.g. `["foo", "bar"]` → `{"foo": null, "bar": null}`; this will also remove duplicates).

Alternatively, substitute `diff` for some other comparator, e.g. `cmp`, `colordiff`, or `vimdiff`, depending on your needs. If all you want is a yes or no answer, consider using `cmp` and passing `--compact-output` to `jq` to not format the output for a potential small performance increase.

Comment: Note that this seems to require version 1.5 or later of `jq`

Comment: @voltagex From looking at the online manual (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.4/#Invokingjq) It seems that it was actually added in 1.4, although I don't know if `jq` does posix style arguments so you may have to invoke `jq -c -S ...`

Comment: A cleaner, visual form IMO is `vimdiff <(jq -S . a.json) <(jq -S . b.json)`

Comment: Yeah, you should remove the `-c` (which makes output compact), style preferences isn't relevant to your answer.

Comment: @odinho-Velmont @Ashwin Jayaprakash It's true that the `c` isn't strictly necessary, but to me there's no reason for cmp to compare identical whitespace, and no reason for jq to bother emitting it. `diff`, `vimdiff`, or any tool that does file comparison will work, but `cmp` is all that's necessary.

Comment: @Erik Okay, I see and accept the reasoning with `cmp`.  To be helpful for quick copy-paste, you could possibly include a visual diff too (e.g. using `diff`), though :)

Answer (score 108):

Use [`jd`](https://github.com/josephburnett/jd#command-line-usage) with the `-set` option:

No output means no difference.

```
$ jd -set A.json B.json
```

Differences are shown as an @ path and + or -.

```
$ jd -set A.json C.json

@ ["People",{}]
+ "Carla"
```

The output diffs can also be used as patch files with the `-p` option.

```
$ jd -set -o patch A.json C.json; jd -set -p patch B.json

{"City":"Boston","People":["John","Carla","Bryan"],"State":"MA"}
```

https://github.com/josephburnett/jd#command-line-usage

Comment: So underrated it should be a misdemeanor. Gives an actual `diff` formatting-compatible output. Amazing.

Comment: You can use the command line tool, or the web tool: http://play.jd-tool.io/

Comment: This is the holy grail tool for futzing with `json` (and `yaml`, after conversion) configs to see why exactly why one's config is not working compared to someone else's.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. However, there should be an option to turn off and on - order within the list contents should be important or not.

Comment: That's what the `-set` flag is for. If you include it, order within lists doesn't matter. If you don't, it will matter (default).

Comment: By the way ijoseph, I added a `-yaml` option so `jd` can read and write yaml as well as json.  Try it out at http://play.jd-tool.io/

Comment: I'd like to try this from CLI, but I am a go newbie and can't figure out how to run it. After running `go get` to install it, `jd` is still not found. I downloaded the latest release from github, `chmod +x` to make it runnable, and only got "exec format error: ./jd" when trying to run int from CLI. On OSX if it matters.

Comment: I was building only for Linux.  But since you asked, I've cross-compiled the latest release: https://github.com/josephburnett/jd/releases/tag/v1.4.0.  Download jd-amd64-darwin which should work on OSX.

Comment: This is awesome, it is a sin that `jd` isn't more known to the general public.

Comment: using Homebrew on MacOS: `brew install jd`

Answer (score 14):

Pulling in the best from the top two answers to get a `jq` based json diff:

```
diff \
  <(jq -S 'def post_recurse(f): def r: (f | select(. != null) | r), .; r; def post_recurse: post_recurse(.[]?); (. | (post_recurse | arrays) |= sort)' "$original_json") \
  <(jq -S 'def post_recurse(f): def r: (f | select(. != null) | r), .; r; def post_recurse: post_recurse(.[]?); (. | (post_recurse | arrays) |= sort)' "$changed_json")
```

This takes the elegant array sorting solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31933234/538507 (which allows us to treat arrays as sets) and the clean bash redirection into `diff` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37175540/538507 This addresses the case where you want a diff of two json files and the order of the array contents is not relevant.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution using the generic function *walk/1*:

```
# Apply f to composite entities recursively, and to atoms
def walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;

def normalize: walk(if type == "array" then sort else . end);

# Test whether the input and argument are equivalent
# in the sense that ordering within lists is immaterial:
def equiv(x): normalize == (x | normalize);
```

Example:

```
{"a":[1,2,[3,4]]} | equiv( {"a": [[4,3], 2,1]} )
```

produces:

```
true
```

And wrapped up as a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

JQ=/usr/local/bin/jq
BN=$(basename $0)

function help {
  cat <<EOF

Syntax: $0 file1 file2

The two files are assumed each to contain one JSON entity.  This
script reports whether the two entities are equivalent in the sense
that their normalized values are equal, where normalization of all
component arrays is achieved by recursively sorting them, innermost first.

This script assumes that the jq of interest is $JQ if it exists and
otherwise that it is on the PATH.

EOF
  exit
}

if [ ! -x "$JQ" ] ; then JQ=jq ; fi

function die     { echo "$BN: $@" >&2 ; exit 1 ; }

if [ $# != 2 -o "$1" = -h  -o "$1" = --help ] ; then help ; exit ; fi

test -f "$1" || die "unable to find $1"
test -f "$2" || die "unable to find $2"

$JQ -r -n --argfile A "$1" --argfile B "$2" -f <(cat<<"EOF"
# Apply f to composite entities recursively, and to atoms
def walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;

def normalize: walk(if type == "array" then sort else . end);

# Test whether the input and argument are equivalent
# in the sense that ordering within lists is immaterial:
def equiv(x): normalize == (x | normalize);

if $A | equiv($B) then empty else "\($A) is not equivalent to \($B)" end

EOF
)
```

POSTSCRIPT: walk/1 is a built-in in versions of jq > 1.5, and can therefore be omitted if your jq includes it, but there is no harm in including it redundantly in a jq script.

POST-POSTSCRIPT: The builtin version of `walk` has recently been changed so that it no longer sorts the keys within an object. Specifically, it uses `keys_unsorted`. For the task at hand, the version using `keys` should be used.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that `walk` was added in jq 1.5. I have been wishing for a compromise operator between `filter` and `map` and it looks like this is it.

Answer (score 3):

There's an answer for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17194704/3029403) that would be useful.

Essentially you can use the Git `diff` functionality (even for non-Git tracked files) which also includes colour in the output:

`git diff --no-index payload_1.json payload_2.json`

Comment: This is sensitive to order, which the OP wanted to ignore

Comment: This is only a colorized text diff (at least in git version 2.30.2), it doesn't understand JSON semantics. You can check this yourself by producing minimized copies of your JSON data (`jq -cSM`) and git diff'ing them.

Answer (score 2):

One more tool for those to which the previous answers are not a good fit, you can try [jdd](https://github.com/zgrossbart/jdd).

It's HTML based so you can either use it online at [www.jsondiff.com](http://www.jsondiff.com/) or, if you prefer running it locally, just download the project and open the index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use this sort and diff tool: http://novicelab.org/jsonsortdiff/ which first sorts the objects semantically and then compares it. It is based on https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonabc

Answer (score 0):

In [JSONiq](https://jsoniq.org), you can simply use the deep-equal function:

```
deep-equal(
  {
    "People": ["John", "Bryan", "Carla"],
    "City": "Boston",
    "State": "MA"
  },
  {
    "People": ["Bryan", "John"],
    "State": "MA",
    "City": "Boston"
  }
)
```

which returns

```
false
```

You can also read from files (locally or an HTTP URL also works) like so:

```
deep-equal(
  json-doc("path to doc A.json"),
  json-doc("path to doc B.json")
)
```

A possible implementation is [RumbleDB](https://rumbledb.org/).

However, you need to be aware that it is not quite correct that the first two documents are the same: [JSON](https://json.org) defines arrays as ordered lists of values.

```
["Bryan", "John"]
```

is not the same as:

```
["John", "Bryan"]
```