# How can I completely sort arbitrary JSON using jq?

Tags: json, sorting, jq

I want to diff two JSON text files.  Unfortunately they're constructed in arbitrary order, so I get diffs when they're semantically identical.  I'd like to use jq (or whatever) to sort them in any kind of full order, to eliminate differences due only to element ordering.

--sort-keys solves half the problem, but it doesn't sort arrays.

I'm pretty ignorant of jq and don't know how to write a jq recursive filter that preserves all data; any help would be appreciated.

I realize that line-by-line 'diff' output isn't necessarily the best way to compare two complex objects, but in this case I know the two files are very similar (nearly identical) and line-by-line diffs are fine for my purposes.

[Using jq or alternative command line tools to diff JSON files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930041) answers a very similar question, but doesn't print the differences.  Also, I want to save the sorted results, so what I really want is just a filter program to sort JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jq or alternative command line tools to diff JSON files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930041/using-jq-or-alternative-command-line-tools-to-diff-json-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just had a need for this and didn't want to have to define a bunch of functions since I'd like this to be a simple one liner. Fortunately the following worked out:

```
jq -S 'walk(if type == "array" then sort else . end)'
```

Here's an example:

```
$ echo '{"foo":"bar","zzz":true,"list":["a","c","b",{"nested":[1,3,2]}]}' |
  jq -S 'walk(if type == "array" then sort else . end)'
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "list": [
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
    {
      "nested": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ]
    }
  ],
  "zzz": true
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Here is a solution using a generic function *sorted_walk/1* (so named for the reason described in the postscript below).

> normalize.jq:

```
# Apply f to composite entities recursively using keys[], and to atoms
def sorted_walk(f):
  . as $in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | sorted_walk(f)) } ) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( sorted_walk(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;

def normalize: sorted_walk(if type == "array" then sort else . end);

normalize
```

Example using bash:

```
diff <(jq -S -f normalize.jq FILE1) <(jq -S -f normalize.jq FILE2)
```

POSTSCRIPT: The builtin definition of `walk/1` was revised after this response was first posted: it now uses `keys_unsorted` rather than `keys`.

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks!  I see you posted a variation of this solution in the related post, but the simpler example here answered a number of questions.

Answer (score 16):

> I want to diff two JSON text files.

Use [`jd`](https://github.com/josephburnett/jd#command-line-usage) with the `-set` option:

No output means no difference.

```
$ jd -set A.json B.json
```

Differences are shown as an @ path and + or -.

```
$ jd -set A.json C.json

@ ["People",{}]
+ "Carla"
```

The output diffs can also be used as patch files with the `-p` option.

```
$ jd -set -o patch A.json C.json; jd -set -p patch B.json

{"City":"Boston","People":["John","Carla","Bryan"],"State":"MA"}
```

https://github.com/josephburnett/jd#command-line-usage

Comment: Love learning about new tools that make my life easier. Thanks for sharing the answer using the "new to me" `jd` :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised this isn't a more popular question/answer. I haven't seen any other json deep sort solutions. Maybe everyone likes solving the same problem over and over.

Here's an wrapper for [@peak's excellent solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38266731/839369) that wraps it into a shell script that works in a pipe or with file args.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# json normalizer function
# Recursively sort an entire json file, keys and arrays
# jq  --sort-keys is top level only
# Alphabetize a json file's dict's such that they are always in the same order
# Makes json diff'able and should be run on any json data that's in source control to prevent excessive diffs from dict reordering.

[ "${DEBUG}" ] && set -x
TMP_FILE="$(mktemp)"
trap 'rm -f -- "${TMP_FILE}"' EXIT

cat > "${TMP_FILE}" <<-EOT
# Apply f to composite entities recursively using keys[], and to atoms
def sorted_walk(f):
  . as \$in
  | if type == "object" then
      reduce keys[] as \$key
        ( {}; . + { (\$key):  (\$in[\$key] | sorted_walk(f)) } ) | f
  elif type == "array" then map( sorted_walk(f) ) | f
  else f
  end;

def normalize: sorted_walk(if type == "array" then sort else . end);

normalize
EOT

# Don't pollute stdout with debug output
[ "${DEBUG}" ] && cat $TMP_FILE > /dev/stderr

if [ "$1" ] ; then
    jq -S -f ${TMP_FILE}  $1
else
    jq -S -f ${TMP_FILE} < /dev/stdin
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

`jq` has a `--sort-keys` option you can use.

See the [`jq` manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/jq.1.html) for reference.

Comment: From the OP: "--sort-keys solves half the problem, but it doesn't sort arrays."