# jq to diff json in bash

Tags: json, diff, jq

I have 2 json objects comming from a rest api. I want to compare if they are the same object.
objectA:

```
{
  "type": {
    "S": "equal"
  },
  "preFilter": {
    "BOOL": true
  }
}
```

objectB:

```
{
  "preFilter": {
    "BOOL": true
  },
  "type": {
    "S": "equal"
  }
}
```

They are the same, but an md5sum will see them as different. I tried inserting them in 2 different files, and compare the files using something proposed
[here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930041/using-jq-or-alternative-command-line-tools-to-diff-json-files) but I would like to know if it's possible to use jq on the fly to compare variables.

I've been trying to change

```
--argfile a a.json
```

for

```
--arg a $a
```

(being $a a json string) with no luck. Any idea how to approach strings, not files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jq or alternative command line tools to compare JSON files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930041/using-jq-or-alternative-command-line-tools-to-compare-json-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be simplest to use the `--argjson` command-line option, e.g.

```
jq -n --argjson a "$a" --argjson b "$b" '$a == $b'
```

Of course there are alternatives, e.g. using `jq -s` ...