# git diff files not in repository against files in repository

Tags: git, git-diff, git-untracked

I have taken over a project where files on a server are not in a git repository. A git repository was created at some point, but files were still edited on the server without being added to the repository and tracked. Is there a way that I can perform a git diff on the server files against a git repository to see how far off I am?

Comment: Copy the files from server to local git repository and do git diff.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17194704/4036946 (`git diff --no-index f0 f1`)

Comment: If git is installed on the server

    `git diff --cached . // will show changes between staged and last commit`
    `git diff . // will show all staged but modified in working directory`.

also add --stat switch to see summary of files

Comment: Can --no-index have one of the files be a remote repository or branch?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using `vimdiff` instead of `git diff`?

You can compare any two files using `vimdiff`, it'll open both files next to each other, and highlight the changes.

`vimdiff <path_to_file1> <path_to_file2>`

Comment: I have not. I will try it today. Thanks. It looks vimtastic!