# how to use magit to diff two different files outside of repo?

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I'd like to use magit to diff two files, only one of which lives in a repo. This is addressed for git cli here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5637364 but I can't figure out how to do it with Magit. If it matters, I should also note that I am on windows.

Comment: I thin you should try `ediff`

Comment: thanks. that gets me a diff, which helps. It's not in the magit interface, however. Any idea how to do it using magit?

Comment: When you do `M-x magit-diff` it pops-up a menu with options. One of the actions is `p` - Diff paths. It will ask you to specify any two files, and one can be indeed outside of a repo. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [magit documentation](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Diffing.html), it says that you can use the `magit-diff-paths` command.

> `d p`     (`magit-diff-paths`)
>
> Show changes between any two files on disk.

So you can either call it through <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `magit-diff-paths` or <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `magit-diff` and then from the `Actions` menu, choose option `p`.

Comment: perfect. thansk.